# Let $f : \mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ be $f(n) = 3n + 2.$ Find $g : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ with $g \circ f$ is the identity function on $\mathbb Z.$

Tags: functions

I'm aware that f isn't bijective so it cannot have an inverse function. So g cannot be an inverse function to f. Knowing this, I know some people express such undefined inverses in terms of a piecewise function but I'm not too sure.

Can someone help me out on this please?

I guess if g : Z → Z is defined by $(n-2)/3$ that would be make g ◦ f the identity function on Z, I'm not too sure though.

Edit: I understand that $(n-2)/3$ can't be the inverse to f but how can I work out the title?

Comment: $g(n)=\frac{n-2}3$ is not a function $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z.$ For example, $g(3)=\frac13.$

Comment: The inverse only exists for integers of the form $3n+2$.

Comment: Yes, there is no inverse, but there is a left-inverse. @Vishu (Indeed, there are uncountably many left inverses.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes your right, so how would you construct the g?

Comment: The trouble with the obvious inverse is that $n\mapsto (n-2)/3$ does not map integers to integers (e.g., it maps 3 to 1/3). So it only works as an inverse on the image of $f$, rather than on all of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Semiclassical but I don't understand how else you could approach this?

Comment: $$\left\lfloor\frac{n-2}{3}\right\rfloor$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $K = f(\Bbb Z)$. It's clear that we must have

$$ g(k) = \frac{k-2}{3} \in \Bbb Z $$

for all $k\in K$. What should $g$ be elsewhere? Actually, it doesn't matter, because $g\circ f$ will only feed elements of $K$ to $g$, and so we will get the identity function regardless of what $g$ does to elements of $\Bbb Z - K$.

In other words, for any $h: \Bbb Z-K \to \Bbb Z$,

$$ g(n) = \begin{cases} \frac{n-2}{3} & n\in K \\ h(n) & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

is a solution.

Comment: Thanks. I have a question, I was taught that a function that isn't invertible can have an inverse relation if it's applied to a subset of f's domain. Would g be an inverse relation in this case?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to turn non-invertible functions into invertible ones by changing the domain or codomain. The domain of $f$ is relevant when it fails to be one-to-one, as we can then restrict to a subdomain which removes the offending duplicates. In this case, however, $f$ failed to be onto, and so we essentially restricted the codomain instead.